# Fluentd logs not sent to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluent-bit

I have a cluster in VirtualBox to learn kubernetes.
I have a deployment that contains MySQL and phpMyAdmin. I created a DemonSet that has the fluentd image and collects the logs to transmit them to elastics at ip 10.0.2.11.

I don't understand why it doesn't connect to elactic and this log appears:

```
2023-08-28 11:28:49 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: "2023-08-28T11:28:48.393333576Z stdout F 2023-08-28 11:28:48.393 [INFO][64] monitor-addresses/autodetection_methods.go 103: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface enp0s8: 192.168.88.34/24"
2023-08-28 11:29:03 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: "2023-08-28T11:29:02.751461094Z stdout F 2023-08-28 11:29:02.751 [INFO][60] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 22 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m1.5s: avg=19ms longest=172ms (resync-filter-v4,resync-mangle-v4,update-filter-v4)"
2023-08-28 11:29:32 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: "2023-08-28T11:29:31.817507758Z stdout F 2023-08-28 11:29:31.817 [INFO][60] felix/int_dataplane.go 1836: Received *proto.HostMetadataV4V6Update update from calculation graph msg=hostname:\"k8s-worker1\" ipv4_addr:\"192.168.88.34/24\" labels:<key:\"beta.kubernetes.io/arch\" value:\"amd64\" > labels:<key:\"beta.kubernetes.io/os\" value:\"linux\" > labels:<key:\"kubernetes.io/arch\" value:\"amd64\" > labels:<key:\"kubernetes.io/hostname\" value:\"k8s-worker1\" > labels:<key:\"kubernetes.io/os\" value:\"linux\" > "
2023-08-28 11:29:49 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not matched: "2023-08-28T11:29:48.394164263Z stdout F 2023-08-28 11:29:48.393 [INFO][64] monitor-addresses/autodetection_methods.go 103: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface enp0s8: 192.168.88.34/24"
```

configmap.yaml

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: fluentd
data:
  fluent.conf: |-
    @include ignore_fluent_logs.conf
    @include containers.conf
    @include kubernetes.conf
    @include pods-with-annotation.conf
    #@include file-fluent.conf
    @include elasticsearch.conf
  ignore_fluent_logs.conf: |-
    # Do not collect fluentd logs
    <label @FLUENT_LOG>
      <match fluent.**>
        @type null
        @id ignore_fluent_logs
      </match>
    </label>
  tail_container_parse.conf: |-
    <parse>
      @type "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE'] || 'json'}"
      time_format "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TIME_FORMAT'] || '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'}"
    </parse>
  containers.conf: |-
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_container_logs
      path "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PATH'] || '/var/log/containers/*.log'}"
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_TAG'] || 'kubernetes.*'}"
      exclude_path "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH'] || use_default}"
      read_from_head true
      @include tail_container_parse.conf
    </source>
  kubernetes.conf: |-
    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type kubernetes_metadata
      @id filter_kube_metadata
      annotation_match [ "fluentd.active"]
      de_dot false
      kubernetes_url "#{ENV['FLUENT_FILTER_KUBERNETES_URL'] || 'https://' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST') + ':' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT') + '/api'}"
      verify_ssl "#{ENV['KUBERNETES_VERIFY_SSL'] || true}"
      ca_file "#{ENV['KUBERNETES_CA_FILE']}"
      skip_labels "#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_LABELS'] || 'false'}"
      skip_container_metadata "#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_CONTAINER_METADATA'] || 'false'}"
      skip_master_url "#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_MASTER_URL'] || 'false'}"
      skip_namespace_metadata "#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_METADATA_SKIP_NAMESPACE_METADATA'] || 'false'}"
      watch "#{ENV['FLUENT_KUBERNETES_WATCH'] || 'true'}"
    </filter>
  pods-with-annotation.conf: |-
    # Filter records with annotation fluentd.active=true
    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type grep
      <regexp>
        key $["kubernetes"]["annotations"]["fluentd.active"]
        pattern "^true$"
      </regexp>
    </filter> 
    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type record_transformer
      remove_keys $.docker.container_id,$.kubernetes.container_image_id,$.kubernetes.pod_id,$.kubernetes.namespace_id,$.kubernetes.master_url,$.kubernetes.labels.pod-template-hash
    </filter>
  file-fluent.conf: |-
    <match **>
      @type file
      path /tmp/file-test.log
    </match>
  elasticsearch.conf: |-
    <match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      @id out_es
      @log_level info
      include_tag_key true
      host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
      port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
      path "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PATH']}"
      scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
      ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
      ssl_version "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERSION'] || 'TLSv1_2'}"
      user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER'] || use_default}"
      password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'] || use_default}"
      reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'false'}"
      reconnect_on_error "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RECONNECT_ON_ERROR'] || 'true'}"
      reload_on_failure "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_ON_FAILURE'] || 'true'}"
      log_es_400_reason "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ES_400_REASON'] || 'false'}"
      logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'fluentd'}"
      logstash_dateformat "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_DATEFORMAT'] || '%Y.%m.%d'}"
      logstash_format "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_FORMAT'] || 'true'}"
      index_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_INDEX_NAME'] || 'fluentd'}"
      target_index_key "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TARGET_INDEX_KEY'] || use_nil}"
      type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_TYPE_NAME'] || 'fluentd'}"
      include_timestamp "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_INCLUDE_TIMESTAMP'] || 'false'}"
      template_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_NAME'] || use_nil}"
      template_file "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_FILE'] || use_nil}"
      template_overwrite "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_TEMPLATE_OVERWRITE'] || use_default}"
      sniffer_class_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_SNIFFER_CLASS_NAME'] || 'Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchSimpleSniffer'}"
      request_timeout "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_REQUEST_TIMEOUT'] || '5s'}"
      application_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_APPLICATION_NAME'] || use_default}"
      suppress_type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SUPPRESS_TYPE_NAME'] || 'true'}"
      enable_ilm "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLE_ILM'] || 'false'}"
      ilm_policy_id "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY_ID'] || use_default}"
      ilm_policy "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY'] || use_default}"
      ilm_policy_overwrite "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_ILM_POLICY_OVERWRITE'] || 'false'}"
      <buffer>
        flush_thread_count "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
        flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
        chunk_limit_size "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '2M'}"
        queue_limit_length "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
        retry_max_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
        retry_forever true
      </buffer>
    </match>
```

demonset.yaml

```
piVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.15.3-debian-elasticsearch7-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "10.0.2.11"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          # If the name of the Kubernetes node the plugin is running on is set as an environment variable with the name K8S_NODE_NAME, it will reduce cache misses and needless calls to the Kubernetes API.
          - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          # - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH
          #   value: >
          #     [
          #     "/var/log/containers/fluentd-*",
          #     "/var/log/containers/kube-proxy-*"
          #     ]
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: fluentd-config
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: dockercontainerlogdirectory
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: fluentd-config
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-config
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: dockercontainerlogdirectory
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

rbac.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: fluentd
```

Comment: Where is ES deployed? Do you have network connectivity from K8s to 10.0.2.11?

Comment: ES is on another VM with ip 10.0.2.11. Yes, there is a connection between k8s and ES

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.